# jquery drag removing an element changes position of other dropped element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have used jQuery drag functionality in my application.
So what is happening is if I have multiple div's which I have used drag functionality and if I remove one div and remaining div's are changing its positions.

Following is the changes which i tried to solve this:

Tried adding `position:absolute`  But still it doesn't work for me.

Here is my Div.

```
<div class="form-group movable col-2" id="div_1_2"  style="height:30px">
```

Every Div of mine has its own unique Id's.

```
$("#div_1_2").draggable({
            cancel: 'text',
            drag: function(event,ui)
            {
                dragposition = ui.position;
                
                //Here i am adding positions of left and right to my json index 
            },
});
```

Here is my Remove particular Div code:

```
function getRmControllers()  
{
    //Here I have code for removing particular index from json
    $('#div_1_2').remove();
}
```

So far this is the code I am using, can anyone help me where I did mistake and how to resolve this.

Comment: could you try hiding the div instead?

Comment: No let me try once